# Shortcut to calculate the mean of columns in a data frame

Tags: r, sapply

I have the following data frame:

```
Gene <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6")
> A1.1 <- c(1,1,2,4,3,5)
> A1.2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
> B1.1 <- c(2,2,3,5,5,5)
> B1.2 <- c(1,2,3,5,5,5)
> A2.1 <- c(3,2,5,6,6,6)
> A2.2 <- c(1,1,2,2,4,6)
> B2.1 <- c(2,1,4,5,7,4)
> B2.2 <- c(1,3,4,5,2,3)
> df <- data.frame(Gene,A1.1,A1.2,B1.1,B1.2,A2.1,A2.2,B2.1,B2.2)
> df
  Gene A1.1 A1.2 B1.1 B1.2 A2.1 A2.2 B2.1 B2.2
1    1    1    1    2    1    3    1    2    1
2    2    1    2    2    2    2    1    1    3
3    3    2    3    3    3    5    2    4    4
4    4    4    4    5    5    6    2    5    5
5    5    3    5    5    5    6    4    7    2
6    6    5    6    5    5    6    6    4    3
```

I wish to calculate the average across samples (columns) of the same letter/number for each gene (row).

ie. calculate the average of each gene (#1-6) for both A1 samples, both A2 samples, both B1 samples and both B2 samples.

I know I can do this the long way using `apply()`

Ex,

```
> A1_df <- data.frame(df$A1.1, df$A1.2)
> A1 <- apply(A1_df, 1, mean)
> A1
[1] 1.0 1.5 2.5 4.0 4.0 5.5
```

But is there a shortcut way of doing this using `sapply()` such that I end up with a new data frame where the columns are now "A1", "A2", "B1", "B2"?

Let me know if anything is unclear

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we may use `split.default` on the numeric columns by removing the `.` and digits following it in the column names to split in to a list of data.frame, then loop over the `list` with `sapply` and get the `mean` with `rowMeans`

```
sapply(split.default(df[-1], sub("\\.\\d+", "", names(df)[-1])), rowMeans)
```

-output

```
   A1  A2  B1  B2
1 1.0 2.0 1.5 1.5
2 1.5 1.5 2.0 2.0
3 2.5 3.5 3.0 4.0
4 4.0 4.0 5.0 5.0
5 4.0 5.0 5.0 4.5
6 5.5 6.0 5.0 3.5
```

---

Or reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and do group by `mean`.  Here, the `names_pattern` is capturing (`(.*)`) the characters before the `.` and digits in the column names and that will be the `.value` column created in the long format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -Gene, names_to = ".value", 
      names_pattern = "(.*)\\.\\d+") %>%
   group_by(Gene) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), mean))
# A tibble: 6 × 5
   Gene    A1    B1    A2    B2
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   1     1.5   2     1.5
2     2   1.5   2     1.5   2  
3     3   2.5   3     3.5   4  
4     4   4     5     4     5  
5     5   4     5     5     4.5
6     6   5.5   5     6     3.5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = 1:6, A1.1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L), 
    A1.2 = 1:6, B1.1 = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L), B1.2 = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L), A2.1 = c(3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), A2.2 = c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L), B2.1 = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 4L), B2.2 = c(1L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Code works great, thank you!